# Example of MS Access SQL IIF to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

Given the syntax rules shown below

- Access: `IF(Condition, ReturnIfTrue, ReturnIfValue)`
- T-SQL: `CASE WHEN Condition THEN ReturnIfTrue ELSE ReturnIfFalse END`

What would the below be formatted to T-SQL be?

```
(((IIf(IsNull(Production!Product_Title) Or Production!Product_Title Like "Process*",
"Not Started", "Started"))="Not Started") And ((Person.Type) Is Not Null))
```

Comment: Please be aware that (a) *SQL* is a language and there is a standard for it which is known as (b) the *SQL Standard*. (c) *SQL Server* is the name of a database management system, and there is a specific SQL Server edition called (d) *Standard*. (e) *PostgreSQL* is a distinct database management system. (f) *T-SQL* is a dialect [used in the database management systems named *SQL Server* and *Sybase* / *SAP ASE*] of the language called *SQL*. (g) *PostgreSQL* does not use the *T-SQL* dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you don't have to use `IIF` or `CASE`

```
(
    (
    Production.Product_Title IS NULL
    OR Production.Product_Title Like 'Process%'
    )
AND Person.Type IS NOT NULL
)
```

FYI, Transact-SQL has [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function starting with 2012.

**UPD**

If you had to return some value:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 
        Production.Product_Title IS NULL
        OR Production.Product_Title Like 'Process%'
    THEN 'Not Started'
    ELSE 'Started'
    END AS [ProductState]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks Denis - but would you know how to drop any strings with "Process*",
"Not Started", "Started" to fall under the alias of  "Not Started"? That's what the MS Access query has in the IIF. I'm also usingAccess 2016.

Comment: If you had to return some value depending on conditions you would have to use either CASE or IIF. But the partial query from your question doesn't return any value. It could be a part of some WHERE clause or something.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Denis!

Answer (score -1):

(((IIf(IsNull(Production!Product_Title) Or Production!Product_Title Like "Process*",
"Not Started", "Started"))="Not Started") And ((Person.Type) Is Not Null))

Comment: Can you please explain how this code snippet answers the question? Answers with explanations are more helpful to the future readers.